# Initializing and scanning a variable in C

Tags: c, initialization, scanf

can anyone please help me out with this in C language
for ex:

```
int a = scanf("%d", &a);
```

doesn't assign the input value to `a`, but instead gives zero only always.

but this works as intended:

```
int a;
int a = scanf("%d", &a);
```

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of fields parsed, **not** any parsed value.

Comment: You should read the documentation for functions you're using

Comment: `int a; int a = scanf(...);` defines variable `a` twice, which is invalid. Did you mean `int a; a = scanf(...);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int a;
int a = scanf("%d", &a);
```

Does not compile because you redefine the variable `a` twice in the same scope.

`scanf("%d", &a)` attempts to parse the characters from `stdin` as the representation of an `int` and if successful stores the value to `a` and returns `1`, otherwise returns `EOF` at end of file and `0` if characters are present but do not represent an `int` value in decimal representation.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, c, res;
    for (;;) {
        res = scanf("%d\n", &a);
        switch (res) {
          case 1:    printf("value input is %d\n", a);
                     break;
          case 0:    printf("input is not a number\n");
                     break;
          case EOF:  printf("end of file detected\n");
                     return 0;
        }
        // read and discard the rest of the input line
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
            continue;
    }
}
```